# IBM Worklight - Is it possible to change ip address of the android device?

Tags: android, ip-address, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to deploy a Worklight application to an Android device, without success. The same application has been deployed to iPad, where there is a function that allows the user to set up the IP address. I know it is not a perfect solution but right now it will serve the purpose.

I want to know if the same function possible in android devices.

Comment: You want to change a static or dynamic ip address ? isn't this controlled by the Internet Provider ?

Comment: well, the ip address is dynamic, I use [http://${local.IPAddress}:8085] and it works in the worklight console, but not with the android emulator, then I have to change the IP address into 10.0.2.2:8080, and it dose not work with the android devices. but I could manage the porblem in iphone and ipad by changing the ip address of the device into the localhost but I can't do the same in samsung tablet or in htc mobile

Comment: Here I found how to change the MAC address - http://www.robmcghee.com/android/changing-the-mac-address-on-android/. For the ip address go to: 1) Goto Settings | Wireless & Networks
2) In the "Wi-Fi Networks" section tap and HOLD your desired configuration
3) Hold for a while
4) Eventually a menu will appear... select "Modify Network"
5) You can change the IP settings from DHCP to Static there!

No way to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Nada,
Please mention what is the Worklight Studio version you are using. From the comments it sounds like Worklight 5.x.

---

Unlike iOS, Android also has an internal server within.

If you use the following in application-descriptor.xml:
`<worklightServerRootURL>http://${local.IPAddress}:8085</worklightServerRootURL>`

The application will look for the Worklight Server **inside** the device. That, will obviously not work.

When using an Android device, be sure that the value you give `worklightServerRootURL` is the IP address of the machine hosting Worklight Server (meaning, the machine where you have Eclipse installed with the Worklight Studio plug-in).

1. Open a CMD window
2. type `ipconfig`
3. Copy the public IP address of the machine
4. Use it as the value for `WorklightServerRootURL`
5. Re-build All and Deploy
6. Run application on device

By doing the above, the application (whether it is installed on iPad, Android emulator or Android device) will always try to reach the actual machine that hosts the server.

**Notes:**

- The feature you're talking about, called "Worklight Settings", **is not meant for end-users**. It should be **turned off** when moving to production
- This feature **does not** change the IP address of the device; it changes the server URL for the application to connect to
- This feature also exists in Android, and is accessible by tapping on the physical menu button in the device and then on the "Worklight Settings" button

  I do suggest, though, that you follow my steps instead, so that your project will be properly configured.
- If you really do mean that you want to change the IP address of the device for whatever reason, that's not related to Worklight.

Comment: I tried your steps and it worked, but I want to publish the application into the appcenter....and in case the end user won't have the source code to change the IP address of the hosting machine. what would be the solution for that? What should I use as a value for {WorklightServerRootURL}?

Comment: The value of worklightServerRootURL should ALWAYS be that of the Worklight Server that application belongs to. Whether you will be publishing the apps to Application Center is irrelevant.